# Is it fine to have template tag inside the root template tag in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I don't know if we can use the `<template>` tag inside the root `template` tag in Vue. Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-red-500 file">
    <div v-for="page in pages" :key="page.id" class="page">
      <div v-for="item_1 in page" :key="item_1.id" class="item_1">
        <div v-for="item_2 in item_1" :key="item_2.id" class="item_2">
          <template v-for="item_3 in item_2" :key="item_3.id">
            <div v-for="item_4 in item_3" :key="item_4.id" class="item_4" :style="{textAlign: item_4.direction}">
              {{ item_4.txt }}
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried the code, and it works fine.

Is it OK to use Vue in such a manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a distinction between a component's root `<template>` tag and one *within* the template.** They are different things that happen to use the same tag, and using the tag within templates is actually a feature of the template "syntax".

As a tag, it is *intended* to be used within the top-level template, as a means of templating (such as looping without creating extra elements). According to [the docs on the `<template>` tag](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#template), it "is used as a placeholder when we want to use a built-in directive without rendering an element in the DOM." If it has at least one of `v-if`, `v-else-if`, `v-else`, `v-for`, or `v-slot` are present, it will be handled specially by Vue. If not, "it will be rendered as a [native `<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) instead."

To quote the docs about the distinction:

> Single-file components use a top-level `<template>` tag to wrap the entire template. That usage is separate from the use of `<template>` described above. That top-level tag is not part of the template itself and doesn't support template syntax, such as directives.